# How might I design a "quick-breakdown" feature to allow easy assembly and disassembly of this floating beds frame supports?

Tags: wood, furniture, strength

I have built a couple floating beds now and assembly and disassembly is very time consuming. I've tried researching possible braces to allow the person who is assembling the frame the quickly connect/disconnect the middle braces. Currently the middle 2x4 boards are screwed into to outer frame.

The boards need to be completely secured due to the fact that the top frame is sitting on top of a smaller frame so it appears to be floating.

In my mind I've always pictured a 2x4 connector that you slide the board into and then close the top so you can't pull it back up. It would have one on each side of the each middle support braces. I just can't find anything similar with my research. [image]

Comment: You should explicitly state your question. So far you've only roughly indicated a dissatisfaction. Maybe something like: "How might I design a "quick-breakdown" feature to allow dissassembly without tools?" or something like that.

Comment: I need to check, are you trying to speed initial assembly (i.e. save time on your end) or make it easier & faster for the end user to re-assemble the platform in their home? I was composing an Answer and then realised I wasn't sure which.

Comment: Have you considered whats going to happen when someone goes to sit on the edge of the bed? I foresee the thing tipping.

Comment: Graphus I'm trying to make it easier on the customer to assemble and disassemble in thier home.

Comment: Ratchet Freak the way that the bed is made there is not enough over hang to tip. I've had 2 people including myself stand on the side (combined total of about 400 pounds) and didn't have an issue.

Answer (score 4):

For starters I would look into half lapping the interior cross members. This way you can have just two supports running the length of the bed, as opposed to ten small pieces running between each cross support. This eliminates any need for screws in your interior cross member supports.

This is very much like building a torsion box. I would also recommend switching to 3/4" plywood, which will lighten it up, while giving you more strength at the half laps.

Now you just need to attach that outside perimeter of the frame.These can still be screwed on if desired, but I would recommend some type of hardware connection, both for strength, and to keep all fasteners inside the frame out of view. L-brackets, joist hangers, your choice really.

[image]